# how to capture particular size of webview

Tags: android, webview

I want to capture particular size of the webview.I can capture the full image of webview by using "capturePicture()" method. And also capture the visible part of the webview by using the following code:

```
webview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
               Bitmap bitmap_resize = null;
               try
               {
               bitmap_resize = Bitmap.createBitmap(webview.getDrawingCache());
               }
               catch(Exception e)
               {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
           webview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

And i want to capture only vrtical part of the webview. But my question is,Is it possible to capture particular size of webview?
Thanks Inadvance.

Comment: You can get the screen size first, then you can call letftOf, rightOf, top and bottom measurements of the webbiew and calculate its size.

Comment: please post the code,if you possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If u really want to capture the half of the web view screen,

first of all we define the screen size before capture, and capture the screen and take the bitmap as you done previously,

I think the following screen will helps you while capture

```
v.layout(0, 0, <width>, <height>);
```

Then capture the layout.

Have a nice coding guys......